# Lightbox2 - Prev and Next arrows not showing up

Tags: lightbox2

I'm using lightbox2 in DreamWeaver and it's great. The only problem is that both the next and prev arrows don't show up, but the X and loading gif show up fine. They are all in my images folder. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure they aren't just showing up below the image? I' currently have a problem where they're displaying way below the image. I have to scroll down to see them.